# Include in project programmatically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, project

How do we include a file in a project using code?

I want to include this file:

[image: File to include]

I also want the equivalent of this:

[image: Include]

In code ... Is it possible?

Comment: are you trying to do this from the program in the project or a separate program?

Comment: @user1937198 I'm trying to do this from a separate program... If that isn't possible though I'll accept doing it from the program in the project.

Comment: actually doing it from a separate program is the only way to do it

Comment: have a look at the visual studio SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286983(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you can include folders like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233390/vc-project-include-in-project-programmatically

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18544354
Also related for solution manipulation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24140413/1007074

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this a few ways.

#### Command Line:

> devenv /command "File.AddExistingSolutionItem fullpath\filename"

#### Project File:

The project file is XML. You can open and modify it like any file.

#### Code:

Use `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` to inspect and modify project files. The `.AddItem()` method is what you're looking for.