# What's the correct usage of Microsoft.Build.Evaluation?

Tags: msbuild

I want to programmatically add an Import to an MSBuild project. The API in this `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` namespace allows me to to this (I'd prefer to achieve the same result through the VS extensibility API but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that so I'm resorting to this API).

If I want to open one or more Projects in a method, look at their Imports, and sometimes add an import, how am I supposed to use `ProjectCollection` object? Do I always create a new ProjectCollection, load projects into it, then unload them all at the end of the method?

I have working code that does what I want, I just can't guess how to 'properly' use this API since there's just the usual low-level reference documentation provided.

Answer (score 5):

Well, in the absence of any advice anywhere I could find on how to use this API I ended up creating a new ProjectCollection any time I wanted to work with a project object, then calling UnloadAllProjects on the ProjectCollection.

```cs
/// <summary>
///  Do something with a Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="projectPath"></param>
/// <param name="worker"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
static T WithProject<T>(string projectPath, Func<Project, T> worker)
{
    var pc = new ProjectCollection();
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projectPath))
            return default(T);
        var evalProject = pc.LoadProject(projectPath);
        return worker(evalProject);
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    finally
    {
        pc.UnloadAllProjects();
    }
}
```

Or, much simpler (from snooping in somebody else's DLL with ILSpy):

```cs
public static Project GetMSBuildProject(string projectPath)
{
    Project project = null;
    if (project == null)
    {
        project = new Project(projectPath, new Dictionary<string, string>(), "12.0", new ProjectCollection());
    }
    return project;
}
```

Comment: I feel your pain. I wish I had more to offer than empathy. It's almost 2 years later and still not much info out there. I'm very impressed with these MsBuild APIs so far, but only the ones I can figure out how to use properly. Thanks for your solution. It is much better than the method I was using!

Comment: Actually, I do have a tad bit to offer. Instead of "new Dictionary<string, string>()", it appears one can simply pass "null". Also, to future-proof that version string literal "12.0", it seems the static property "ProjectCollection.Version.ToString(2)" makes for a good default value (at least so far).