# What's the correct usage of Microsoft.Build.Evaluation (fast forward to 2021)?

Tags: c#, msbuild

So the original question [What's the correct usage of Microsoft.Build.Evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140413/whats-the-correct-usage-of-microsoft-build-evaluation) has the following accepted answer:

```
project = new Project(projectPath, new Dictionary<string, string>(), "12.0", new ProjectCollection());
```

This does not work in 2021 with NuGet package Microsoft.Build 16.8.0.

I would like to evaluate a non SDK style project like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />
...
  <Import Project="..\..\..\Tools\MSBuild\Dayforce.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Please, observe:

**Attempt 1**

```
new Project(projectPath, new Dictionary<string, string>(), "16.0", new ProjectCollection());
```

Results in:

```
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The tools version "16.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "Current".
```

**Attempt 2**

```
new Project(projectPath, new Dictionary<string, string>(), "Current", new ProjectCollection());
```

Results in:

```
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "C:\work\CSTool\CSTool\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\work\CSTool\CSTool\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Current\Microsoft.Common.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

**Attempt 3**

```
new Project(projFilePath, new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["MSBuildExtensionsPath"] = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild",
}, "Current", new ProjectCollection());
```

Results in:

```
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "C:\work\CSTool\CSTool\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\work\CSTool\CSTool\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

We are making progress, Microsoft.Common.props seems to have been imported and now we fail on the last import - Microsoft.CSharp.targets

**Attempt 4**

```
new Project(projFilePath, new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["MSBuildExtensionsPath"] = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild",
    ["MSBuildBinPath"] = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin",
}, "Current", new ProjectCollection());
```

But the result is:

```
System.ArgumentException: The "MSBuildBinPath" property name is reserved.
```

So, what am I missing?

I managed to do what I wanted. However, none of the `Microsoft.Build` NuGet packages worked as expected by me. I checked all the published versions.

What worked for me is reference the Microsoft.Build Dlls found inside the VS 2019 installation directory. Here is my project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And here is the code that works:

```
var project = new Project(projFilePath);
foreach (var compileItem in project.AllEvaluatedItems.Cast<ProjectItem>().Where(item => item.ItemType == "Compile"))
{
    var filePath = compileItem.EvaluatedInclude;
    ...
}
```

I checked the [msbuild github repository](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild) - it does not use the NuGet packages either. Instead it includes the source code for all the relevant libraries and just builds them. And these dlls work too just as the VS dlls work.

So, what is the deal with the NuGet packages? I do not get it. Opened https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/6147

Answer (score 5):

There is an open issue regarding loading a project file that explains current caviats for net5 and net6. https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3434#issuecomment-774280523

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build" Version="17.3.2" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.5.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="17.4.0" ExcludeAssets="runtime" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;

class Program
{
   const string ProjectPath = @"C:\tmp\project.csproj";

   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
      LoadProject();
   }

   private static void LoadProject()
   {
      var buildEngine = new ProjectCollection();
      var project = buildEngine.LoadProject(ProjectPath);
      Console.WriteLine($"OutputType: {project.GetPropertyValue("OutputType")}");
      Console.WriteLine($"TargetFramework: {project.GetPropertyValue("TargetFramework")}");
   }
```

Note how the first usage of MSBuild API has to be in a separate method, because otherwise JIT will try to resolve Microsoft.Build.dll before MSBuildLocator was registered.

In net6 it seems "MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()" is requiered but not in net5.

I did not setup a **MSBUILD_EXE_PATH** as mentioned by others.

Comment: This. Still required with VS2022 and .net6

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core` NuGet package and also set the `MSBUILD_EXE_PATH` environment variable to either MSBuild.exe or MSBuild.dll

https://web.archive.org/web/20210419051516/https://blog.rsuter.com/missing-sdk-when-using-the-microsoft-build-package-in-net-core/

After this just create a project:

```cs
var project = new Project("Path\To\Your\Project");
```

Comment: Having MSBUILD_EXE_PATH is a killer requirement. Not good.

Comment: Why is it a killer requirement?

Comment: Actually, it is OK. My question hard codes the path to MSBuild anyway. I will check it.

Comment: So I had an opportunity to test it. Providing MSBUILD_EXE_PATH is not enough. I will upvote your answer, but provide my own with the details that worked for me.

Comment: I had an opportunity to play with it again. And it just does not work. My .NET 5 application is unable to parse .NET Framework SDK style project files. Even with the `MSBUILD_EXE_PATH` property. The only msbuild DLLs that work are those from the VS distribution, NuGet ones do not work in my case.

Comment: Did you reference both `Microsoft.Build` and `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core`? [Here](https://github.com/KuraiAndras/CsprojToAsmdef/tree/main/Sources/CsprojToAsmdef.Cli) is the project that I used this in

Comment: I reference both. Here is a very important question - what is the target framework of your code and that of the code you are parsing? The NuGet does not work when your code is .NET Core, but you are parsing .NET Framework. Or maybe if your code is SDK style, but the parsed projects are not.

Comment: The code running is .Net Core, the project I'm parsing is .Net Standard with SDK-style csproj

Comment: Try parsing non SDK style projects from .NET Core code. That is my scenario.